# How to prove the boundedness of this integral

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the boundedness on this improper integral.

$$ 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|t-x|} \ dt $$

Thus, it remains to prove there's a bound for all $t$. For I can't manage to find it because $t=x$ is a point where the magnitude blows up.

Comment: It isn’t bounded; the integral is essentially $\int_0^\infty \frac1x\,dx$ which is diverges.

Comment: This integral is unbounded since $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{t}dt$ diverges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$\left.\int_x^\infty\frac1{t-x}dt=\log(t-x)\right|_x^\infty=\lim_{b\to\infty}\log(b-x)-\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\log\epsilon\;(\text{since}\, \,x+\epsilon-x=\epsilon)=\infty-(-\infty)\;$$

...and the above is only a part of your whole integral! Thus, that isn't bounded.